# Approximate area size by counting pixels in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is it possible to extract the number of pixels of some arbitrary filled area to approximate the size of the area in ggplot2?

Specifically, I am using geom_ribbon to highlight some area in a graph and was wondering if there is some generic way to approximate the corresponding area size (without directly referring to the input data). I was thinking about hidden functions or intermediate data which ggplot2 might produce to color each pixel of the blue area on the screen.

```
library(ggplot2)
yint <- 5
x <- 1:100
df <- data.frame(x=x, y=x^0.5)
rib <- df[df$y>=yint,]
ggplot(df, aes(x=x)) + geom_line(aes(y=y)) + geom_hline(aes(yintercept=yint)) + geom_ribbon(data=rib, aes(x=x, ymin=yint, ymax=y), fill='lightblue')
```

**EDIT:**

Adopting lukeA's first solution, I can simply complete my previous ribbon data to form a closed polygon and then use the Polygon() function on it which automatically also calculates the corresponding area.

```
library(sp)
pol <- rbind(rib, c(100,5), c(25,5))
Polygon(pol)@area
```

Comment: If guess it's possible to integrate both functions and look at the difference to estimate the size of the area. But that has not much to do with "number of pixels", which may be different from device to device anyway.

Comment: Yes, but I explicitly want to approximate the size without referring to the input data. In the end, I am interested in the ratio of the sizes of two areas which could be approximated by the ratio of the numbers of pixels.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are two approaches - one is polygon/vector based, the other one is pixel/raster based:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(rgeos)
library(sp)
library(png)

f <- function(x) Polygons(list(Polygon(map_data("world", region = x)[, 1:2])), x)
(tab1 <- gArea(SpatialPolygons(list(f("Germany"), f("France"))), byid=T))
#  Germany   France 
# 41.21485 84.34209 
unname(tab1["France"]/tab1["Germany"])
# [1] 2.046401

map <- map_data("world", region=c("Germany", "France"))
p <- ggplot(map, aes(long, lat, group=group, fill=region)) + 
  geom_polygon() + coord_map() + 
  theme_minimal() + 
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("Germany"="#00BFC4", "France"="#F8766D"), guide="none")
ggsave(tf <- tempfile(fileext = ".png"), p, dpi = 90)
r <- as.matrix(as.raster(readPNG(tf)))
(tab2 <- table(r[r %in% c("#F8766D", "#00BFC4")]))
unname(tab2["#F8766D"]/tab2["#00BFC4"])
#  1.2781
```